# Writing textarea to PHP file from HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, function, file-io

I'm new to [php](/questions/tagged/php) & [html](/questions/tagged/html) so please go easy on me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Add</title>
</head>

<font size="3">

<div id="TextBox">add</div>
<form name="theform" action="add.php" method="get">
<div id="TextBox-Field" style="margin-top:20px;"><textarea class="TextBox" type="text" name="TextBox" required></textarea></div>

<form name="theform" action="DisplayText.html">
<input type="submit" value="Show">
</font> 
</body>
```

I've written this in HTML and i would like it to be able to save the text that the user enters into a file. Preferably I would like that to be done with add.php rather than adding php code to this, if possible?

I'm slightly confused as to where to start, i've googled and watched tutorials but still do not understand

Thank You!

Comment: Break up your problems. Try to write a PHP script that saves a file. Write another one that accepts input from the url (get-parameters = querystring) and echoes it. Then you can practise HTML by actually sending the data through a form. After that you can bring everything together. Trivial as this may be to a pro, for you as a beginner it is too much to do at once, and you will get stuck in the future as well if you cannot break down your problem into smaller pieces.

Comment: By the way, the `font` tag is *very* outdated. If you are new to HTML,  you shouldn't even have heard of it. ;) Also, you HTML is invalid in a few places. For instance you are using an XHTML doctype, but your code isn't XHTML. I would recommend to switch to HTML5, since it is going to be the new standard. Also, use an HTML validator like `http://validator.w3.org/`. Maybe you feel that validity isn't the most important to start with, but it will help you understand the rules of HTML quicker.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the tips, will look into the validator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Change this

```
<form name="theform" action="DisplayText.html">
```

to

```
<form name="theform" action="add.php" method="post">
```

**Step 2:**

`add.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['TextBox']))
{
 file_put_contents('somefile.txt',$_POST['TextBox'],FILE_APPEND);
 echo "Data written successfully";
}
```

Comment: what about somefile.html ?

Comment: @AkhilThayyil You could write it to a HTML file, but you would require additional PHP code to ensure the page isn't broken.

There's also the possibility of an XSS attack if you do so.

Comment: @user3364498, That's why I had given `FILE_APPEND` parameter. That will make sure that the file is not overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to close html tag.......like forgot to open body tag and to close form

```
<font size="3">

<div id="TextBox">add</div>
<form name="theform" action="add.php" method="get">
<div id="TextBox-Field" style="margin-top:20px;"><textarea class="TextBox" type="text" name="TextBox" required></textarea></div>

<form name="theform" action="DisplayText.html">
<input type="submit" value="Show">
</font> 
</body>
```

so replace above code and place following code.it will help you

```
 <body>
<div id="TextBox" style="font-size:3;">add</div>
<form name="theform" action="add.php" method="get">

<div id="TextBox-Field" style="margin-top:20px;  style="font-size:3;">
<textarea class="TextBox" type="text" name="TextBox" required></textarea>
</div>

 </form>

<form name="theform" action="DisplayText.html">
<input type="submit" value="Show">
</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save that than you need to create a databse and then create a table of same number of columns as the data entered html elements you using then on add.php make a connection :
in mysql:

```
 <?php
// Create connection
   mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
   //for eg $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $var1 = $_GET['TextBox'];
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO <tablename> (<columnname>) 
 VALUES ($var1)");

?>
```

Comment: sorry i did not read your below text carefully , i thought u want to save in database ,,